# Casting struct * to int * to be able to write into first field

Tags: c, struct, casting

I've recently found this page:

[Making PyObject_HEAD conform to standard C](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3123/)

and I'm curious about this paragraph:

> Standard C has one specific exception to its aliasing rules precisely designed to support the case of Python: a value of a struct type may also be accessed through a pointer to the first field. E.g. **if a struct starts with an int , the struct * may also be cast to an int * , allowing to write int values into the first field**.

So I wrote this code to check with my compilers:

```
struct with_int {
    int a;
    char b;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct with_int *i = malloc(sizeof(struct with_int));
    i->a = 5;
    ((int *)&i)->a = 8;
}
```

but I'm getting `error: request for member 'a' in something not a struct or union`.

Did I get the above paragraph right? If no, what am I doing wrong?
Also, if someone knows where C standard is referring to this rule, please point it out here. Thanks.

Comment: `((int *)&i)` should be `((int *)i)`

Comment: Or it can be `*(int *)&i`

Comment: @ArchieGertsman That wouldn't work. Where would the value be written into using your example?

Comment: Ahh yes, `i` already holds an address. But I would think that it would need to be dereferenced: `*(int *)i`, no?

Comment: @ArchieGertsman This is different than the previous example, and it would work.

Comment: @Haris: no, it's exactly the same

Comment: Translating "((int *)&i)->a" to plain english:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your interpretation<sup>1</sup> is correct, but the code isn't.

The pointer `i` already points to the object, and thus to the first element, so you only need to cast it to the correct type:

```
int* n = ( int* )i;
```

then you simply dereference it:

```
*n = 345;
```

Or in one step:

```
*( int* )i = 345;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO:IEC 9899:201X 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers 15)
Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a
structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed
padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it:)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues, but this works for me:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct with_int {
    int a;
    char b;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct with_int *i = (struct with_int *)malloc(sizeof(struct with_int));
    i->a = 5;
    *(int *)i = 8;
    printf("%d\n", i->a);
}
```

Output is:
8

Answer (score 0):

Like other answers have pointed out, I think you meant:

```
// Interpret (struct with_int *) as (int *), then
// dereference it to assign the value 8.
*((int *) i) = 8;
```

and not:

```
((int *) &i)->a = 8;
```

However, none of the answers explain specifically why that error makes sense.

Let me explain what `((int *) &i)->a` means:

`i` is a variable that holds an address to a `(struct with_int)`. `&i` is the address on main() function's stack space. This means `&i` is an address, that contains an address to a `(struct with_int)`. In other words, `&i` is a pointer to a pointer to `(struct with_int)`. Then the cast `(int *)` of this would tell the compiler to interpret this stack address as an `int` pointer, that is, address of an `int`. Finally, with that `->a`, you are asking the compiler to fetch the struct member `a` from this `int` pointer and then assign the value 8 to it. It doesn't make sense to fetch a struct member from an `int` pointer. Hence, you get `error: request for member 'a' in something not a struct or union`.

Hope this helps.